# How to work with Aweber API

Tags: aweber

I am using first time Aweber.I am stuck at some point when I used Aweber API.Below are steps to explain my issue:

- I created an account on Aweber labs and created application there. I also retrieved 
  Consumer Key , Application Id and Consumer Secret from there and put in my demo.php .
- When I run this file I had a form with login/password:

Please see this below url :

https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Aq2I3AD7yh7wKBGMGs2pALaP

Now my question is which account's user/pass need to write here. I tried with Aweber lab account details which showing "Notice: Invalid credentials - please retry".

Should I go there "https://www.aweber.com/order.htm" and create paid account to fill there.

Please give your suggestions asap.

With Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The AWeber docs are mindbogglingly poor.  I don't even understand why they have an API: your app and your keys have nothing to do with accessing any user's data.  They just prove to AWeber that yes, you are a developer.... but so what?  You want to access USER data (e.g. their lists and subscribers), and that requires a paid account that you can access.  From everything I can tell, the AWeber API merely lets you recreate the standard login form from https://www.aweber.com/login.htm on your site.

If you can add the oAuth tokens to your code, that would allow you to retrieve data for a given user, but I don't see any examples in the docs of how to do that, or any explanations that "oh yeah, by the way, AWeber handles this completely differently than any other email company out there."  So good luck.

Comment: I share your frustration. The docs make my eyes bleed, and I'm a senior PHP dev. At first they look short and simple until you wonder why they call a list ID an app ID (or if they're even the same thing), and how does one get the accessKey, accessSecret, and account_id?

Comment: @Volomike , I also visited https://labs.aweber.com/snippets/subscribers#cre . I'm not getting how to get accessKey and accessSecret. Also I didn't found any account_id. Can you please guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to log in with your Aweber credentials, not your lab credentials. Also, when you receive your tokens, add them to your code or everyone visiting your form/app will be redirected to that screen because it will be checking for the cookies that Oauth sets and they won't exist.

EDIT: So to be clear,

1. You need to set the Oauth cookie yourself first via code in your script
2. You need to execute the code so the cookies get set in your browser
3. Then you need to look at the values of the cookies to get your accessKey and accessSecret
4. Then you need to hard code those values into your script:

   ```
   $account = $aweber->getAccount($accessKey, $accessSecret);
   ```
5. Lastly, do not forget to remove the Ouath cookie setting in your script

Comment: I followed this advice and I get to the point of getting a valid $account object. But then I wanted to follow the "create subscriber" API step. I had to do print_r($account);die(); to find the account ID (it wasn't obvious) and then get stuck on the loadfromURL() line with this 404 error that reads: NotFoundError - https://labs.aweber.com/docs/troubleshooting#notfound. Of course, the doc URL was absolutely no help at all. In other words, I've determined that this API is broken.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to reference a list by name instead of ID, and these are two different things.

Comment: Typically the oauth keys would get stored in a database and compared against. This API blows for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In the demo code provided by aweber just after this line:

```
$account = $aweber->getAccount($_COOKIE['accessToken'],
    $_COOKIE['accessTokenSecret']);
```

you will be able to get account id

```
$account_id = $account->id;
```

This will give you the account id of the logged-in user.

Answer (score 1):

This PHP tutorial should make the integration pretty painless:
http://engineering.aweber.com/quick-start-api-script-in-php/